# Performance comparison between react hooks and react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn react hooks. I need help in understanding does react functions always reset hook state every time it renders.

Here is a small example of scroll where I am trying to fix the header

```
class Header extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Constructor")
        this.state = {fixed: false};
    }


    handleScroll = () => {
        console.log(window.scrollY);
        console.log(this.state.fixed);
        if (window.scrollY >= 25 && !this.state.fixed) {
            this.setState({
                fixed: true
            });
        } else if(window.scrollY < 25 && this.state.fixed){
            this.setState({
                fixed: false
            });
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log("updated ");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("added");
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("removed");
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Header.js:26 Constructor
Header.js:51 added
Header.js:32 1
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 2
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 5
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 9
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 15
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 20
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 26
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:47 updated 
Header.js:32 31
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 35
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 38
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 40
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 39
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 38
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 35
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 31
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 25
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:32 20
Header.js:33 true
Header.js:47 updated 
Header.js:32 9
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 5
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 2
Header.js:33 false
Header.js:32 0
Header.js:33 false
```

It works fine.

Now with react hooks same logic. I am just trying to look for the behavior of FixedHeader state.

```
const Header = props => {

    console.log("rendering");
    const [FixedHeader, setFixedHeader] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            console.log(window.scrollY);
            console.log(FixedHeader);
            if (window.scrollY >= 30) {
                setFixedHeader(true);
            } else {
                setFixedHeader(false);
            }
        })
    }, []);


    return (
        <div></div>
   );
}
```

Output:

```
Header.js:23 rendering
Header.js:28 1
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 2
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 5
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 9
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 15
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 20
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 26
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 31
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:23 rendering
Header.js:28 35
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:23 rendering
Header.js:28 38
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 40
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 39
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 38
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 35
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 31
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 25
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:23 rendering
Header.js:28 20
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:23 rendering
Header.js:28 14
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 9
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 5
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 2
Header.js:29 false
Header.js:28 0
Header.js:29 false
```

I can't understand this behavior why rendering is called twice, and  FixedHeader is false even when scroll is >= 30.

I am new to js so I think this is the way function work rendering is there 2 times because function got called twice but why twice, and each time function is called all the states need to be set again doesn't it going to impact the performance (I may be wrong).

Note: I have not added html part it is simple header where I am adding class "fixed-top" based on the boolean variable.

Comment: You are passing `[]` to `useEffect`, which means the code only runs the first time the component is rendered. At that point, `FixedHeader` has the value `false`. Each time the component renders a new `FixedHeader` variable is created.

Comment: OMG a perf question about the actual performance of actual code instead of bootless speculation. +1 to you!

Comment: @FelixKling does that mean a lower performance as compared to class.

Comment: If you mean whether adding and removing the event handler every time the value changes takes more time than not doing that, then yes ;) I doubt that this will have any measurable impact though.

Comment: @FelixKling I mean u said  "Each time the component renders a new FixedHeader variable is created". so if have many states then this may be a problem.

Comment: When a function gets called, its body is evaluated again. The same happens with the `render` method of a class component. Whether or not the function call is expensive depends on what the function does. While there is a theoretical performance difference between a function that declares a variable and one that doesn't, you will never be able to measure that. The slow parts of JavaScript running in a browser are not the function calls or the variable declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason "rendering" is displayed twice is because you are using different conditions.

For the class component you use:

```
if (window.scrollY >= 25 && !this.state.fixed) {
    // ...
} else if (window.scrollY < 25 && this.state.fixed) {
    // ...
}
```

While the function component uses:

```
if (window.scrollY >= 30) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

To fix this issue you need to add the check the current state.

However like you've already noticed checking `FixedHeader` value will always result in the same value (it is not getting updated). So we need to tackle that problem first.

The problem is that `setFixedHeader` doesn't update the `FixedHeader` in the current context. It tells React to re-render using the passed value as the new `FixedHeader` on the next `Header` call, but `FixedHeader` in the current context is never changed.

[`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) allows you to return a function that handles clean-up. This function runs if the component unmounts, or before the next call of `useEffect` (when the dependency list has changed). Adding `FixedHeader` to the dependency list will remove the previous scroll event handler (using the returned clean-up function) and adds a new scroll event handler using the new `FixedHeader` value when the `FixedHeader` value changes.

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const Header = props => {
    console.log("rendering");
    const [fixed, setFixed] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            console.log(window.scrollY);
            console.log(fixed);
            
            if (window.scrollY >= 30 && !fixed) {
                setFixed(true);
            } else if (window.scrollY < 30 && fixed) {
                setFixed(false);
            }
        };
        
        document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        return () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }, [fixed]);

    return null;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.querySelector("#header-container"));
```

```css
body { height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="header-container"></div>
```

Comment: As @FelixKling  said "Each time the component renders a new FixedHeader variable is created". so I want to know should I stick to classes or change my code to react hooks. (if performance is the criteria ).

Comment: @anoop Yes each time the component renders new variables are created, but the lifespan of those is also shorter. For simple logic the functional components are often cleaner to look at. I wouldn't worry too much about performance until it becomes an issue. Pre-optimizations can sometimes leave you with code that's harder to understand, which in turn increases development time.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't understand this behavior why rendering is called twice, and
> FixedHeader is false even when scroll is >= 30.

I guess it is because of closure, the function remember FixedHeader value, which it had in a moment, function was created... you can create some object outside component and write FixedHeader to its property if you really need to see value inside your scroll event callback

```
const holder = {}
const Header = props => {
    const [FixedHeader, setFixedHeader] = useState('false');
    holder.value = FixedHeader

    const handleScroll = function () {
      console.log(window.scrollY)
      console.log(holder.value)
      if (window.scrollY >= 30) {
        setFixedHeader('true');
      } else {
        setFixedHeader('false');
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, []);



    return (
```

but because of react does not rerender immidiately sometimes value will not be right

Comment: *"Right now i can not see the way how to handle this"* Either `FixedHeader` needs to be added to `useEffect`'s dependency list and the event listeners needs to be properly removed, or one could use a ref to get the "current" value of `FixedHeader` (assuming that the ref is updated accordingly).

Comment: There is no need for `holder` if you add `FixedHeader` to the dependency list (now that you are removing the event handler anyway).

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, you are right, i changed my answer  using the second way, but first one with dependencies seems more correct

Comment: @FelixKling, but i just doubt if it really needed to console.log each scroll, i do not see sence in it so may be each time when component rerenders add event listener and remove is not nice solution... but anyway the cause is clear

Comment: Of course. I assume it's just for testing to see what's going on.

Comment: problem with boolean variable can be solved by your method, but what about rendering method getting called twice.

Comment: @anoop, there is no problem, you can make an array of holders and ```const ind = useState(holders.length); if (ind === holders.length) holders.push({})```